# HTTP/HTTPS client, "connection reset" on HTTPS requests

Tags: java, sockets, http, https

I'm trying to make a simple **HTTP/HTTPS client using java**. What i have done as of now in my Client.java file is here.

Everything is working good when i try to access www.google.com:80.  I'm getting the full HTML content in my response BufferedReader.

But, when i try to access www.google.com:443, there is no data coming through BufferedReader

For www.facebook.com:80,

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

Also, when i try with www.facebook.com:443, Getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Where am i going wrong? Why am i not able to get any response for the HTTPS sites?

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //String host = args[0];
        //int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        //String path = args[2];

        int port = 80;
        String host = "www.google.com";
        String path = "/";

        //Opening Connection
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("======================================");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        System.out.println("======================================");

        //Declare a writer to this url
        PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);

        //Declare a listener to this url
        BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        //Sending request to the server
        //Building HTTP request header
        request.print("GET "+path+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"); //"+path+"
        request.print("Host: "+host+"\r\n");
        request.print("Connection: close\r\n");
        request.print("\r\n");
        request.flush();

        System.out.println("Request Sent!");
        System.out.println("======================================");

        //Receiving response from server
        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = response.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(responseLine);
        }
        System.out.println("======================================"); 
        System.out.println("Response Recieved!!");
        System.out.println("======================================");
        request.close();
        response.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Several issues here, such as using the platform line terminator when the HTTP line terminator is defined as `\r\n`, and assuming the response body is all text, but why are you doing this at all, when `HttpURLConnection` already exists? And don't use quote formatting for things that aren't quotes.

Comment: I've given a try with `\r\n` also, still the same issue. I'm very new to Socket programming. So i'm doing this way, assuming this is the best way to implement a HTTP client-server.

Comment: It isn't. Create a `URL;` get an `HttpURLConnection` from it; set whatever request headers you need; get the output stream; read it. You're reinvening the wheel.

Comment: Ya i never knew there was a wheel before! Thanks for your comments! I'll learn them to make our life easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS is encrypted; it's HTTP via SSL. You can't just send raw HTTP requests. The server will drop your connection immediately if you start sending data without establishing a secure connection first (hence the connection reset error). You have to establish an SSL connection first. You'd want to use an [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) (via [`SSLSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), see also [example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32388)) instead of a `Socket` in that case.

It's as simple as changing one line of your code for the HTTPS case (well, three if you count the exception specification and the port number change to 443):

```
Socket clientSocket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);
```

Note that `clientSocket` will be an instance of `SSLSocket` (which is derived from `Socket`) in this case.

However, if you're doing this as part of a larger application (as opposed to just a learning experience), consider existing libraries, such as Apache's [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) (which supports HTTPS as well) or the built-in [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and [`HttpsURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) if you need something more basic. If you need to embed a server in an application you can use the built-in [`HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) or [`HttpsServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html).

Also issues that EJP mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910223/http-https-client-using-java-socket-programming/28910448#comment46079778_28910223).

Comment: This is pure learning! `SSLSocket` giving me a bunch of methods to override! Any help here how to do so to make this work?

Comment: @Prem Look at the `SSLSocket` docs a little more closely. You don't create them directly or generally subclass them on your own, you create them with an [`SSLSocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) (when in doubt, see related classes) (don't forget the base methods in [`SocketFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html)). Example: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32388